# Metro App (ScaleTransform) Content of ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, xaml, containers, contentpresenter

I have a `ContentPresenter` and i try to scale the `Content = ""`(FrameworkElement)`. 
Because if the Content.Size is to big it get cut off. I prepared these pictures to explain my problem.

We start from here. As you can see there is a part missing (yellow Panel is cuted).

[image: This is the result without <code>ScaleTransform</code>]

So what I tried was `ScaleTransform`.
(XAML)

```
        <ContentPresenter Content="SomeContent"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="0">
            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75"></ScaleTransform>
            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>

        </ContentPresenter>
```

So after I added the `ScaleTransform` I got this result.
[image] 
And obviously my Content got scaled, but its still cutted.

So I stopped to try it in XAML and this is what came out in c# .

```
    public static FrameworkElement ScaleContent(FrameworkElement element, Size space)
    {
        ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        double height = element.ActualHeight;
        double width = element.ActualWidth;

        if (height == 0 || width == 0)
        {
            element.Measure(new Size(space.Width,
                space.Height));

            element.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, element.DesiredSize.Width, element.DesiredSize.Height));
            height = element.ActualHeight;
            width = element.ActualWidth;

        }

        double scaleWidth = space.Width / width;
        double scaleHeight = space.width / height;

        scaleTransform.ScaleX = scaleWidth;
        scaleTransform.ScaleY = scaleHeight;

        element.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;
        return element;
    }
```

And this is what came out.
[image: ScaleTransform in Class]

To let you see the complete Example. I saved a Picture in a bigger Format, where the Content fits.
[image: This should it look like]

So what do you think is the problem ?
Thank you !

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Maybe a little more explanation or a quick visual to display your problem? Would also help to know what you're working in (WP,WRT,WPF,SL, etc?)

Comment: Hey Chris, i updated my question.

Comment: Oh, ya, throw it in a `ViewBox` and you're done. Cheers!

Comment: But i want to use this for printing. And I think a `Viewbox` ist not the best choice for it. For Example if I dont want to scale it some times. How can I do this with a `ViewBox`.

Comment: The second thing is that `ViewBox` is not so easy in changing the `Content` betweent `Views`.